# Prevent Looping in jQuery Advanced News Ticker (Forking/Modifying)

Tags: javascript, jquery, news-ticker

I realize this question is rather niche and should be directed at the author on [github](https://github.com/risq/jquery-advanced-news-ticker) or otherwise.

But, the plug-in has not been updated in over 5 years, and, being a relatively straight forward plug-in, I"m trying to modify it so that it prevents it from looping elements when `Previous` or `Next` is clicked.

See here for a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/zwb1vr96/2/

As you can see, hitting the `Previous` button while it is on `1` brings it to `3`.

Similarly, if it's on `3` and you click `Next`, it loops back to `1`.

As seen in the fiddle, I gave a length variable (`var listlength = $("#newsticker li").length;`) inside the plug-in function which tells me how many list (or `li`) items are in my list.

The next modification must be within these lines:

```
 if(this.options.nextButton && typeof(this.options.nextButton[0]) !== 'undefined')
                                this.options.nextButton.click(function(e) {
                                        this.moveNext();
                                        this.resetInterval();
                                }.bind(this));
 if(this.options.prevButton && typeof(this.options.prevButton[0]) !== 'undefined')
                                this.options.prevButton.click(function(e) {
                                        this.movePrev();
                                        this.resetInterval();
                                }.bind(this));
```

But I am kept up on the fact that this plug-in works by defining a set `height` and doesn't modify unseen `li` items.

Here's what I'm trying:

adding a `var count = 0;`

and to the `next` button

```
                            this.options.nextButton.click(function(e) {
                         if (count == 3) { return false; }
                            else { count++; }
```

as well as to the previous button

```
  this.options.prevButton.click(function(e) {
                                if (count == 0) { return false; }
                                else { count--; }
```

It works to an extent-- but is still buggy and is not giving the proper count to return false on.

[JsFiddle Attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/8fcz9470/)

How can I create a variable within these `Previous` and `Next` script functions above to know which list item it is currently on (in the jsfiddle example - `1`, `2`, or `3`) and subsequently prevent the event from firing if my list item is on `1` when the Previous button is clicked as well as prevent the firing of the Next button if the list item being shown is at `3` (hence preventing the looping feature as described above).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that the ticker has no option to prevent the constant auto-removal/appending of ticker items as it animates:

[image]

you might consider this [alternative plugin](http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/downloads/jquery.vticker.js?v=1.21) that has an option of `autoAppend` which you could set to `false`, then I would expect that the ticker stops at the end without looping (also if you manually control it).

Comment: Hm. Hadn't came across that one. I made a count function posted below.. as far as I know it eliminates the need for auto-removal and appending (although yes, that is what I was originally seeking to bind too).  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did find a solution -- it seems rather basic but it does function at least in my limited example:

https://jsfiddle.net/8fcz9470/5/

> new variables in js function

```
    var listlength = $("#newsticker li").length;
    var count = 1;
```

And them modifying the `Next` Button

```
 this.options.nextButton.click(function(e) {
                             if (count == 3) {
                             alert(count);
                             return false; 
                             }
                             else if (count < 3) { 
                             count++;
                             alert(count);
                                        this.moveNext();
                                        this.resetInterval();
                             }
                                }.bind(this));
```

And `Previous` button

```
  this.options.prevButton.click(function(e) {
                                if (count == 1) { alert(count); return false; }
                                else if (count > 0) { 
                                count--; 
                                alert(count);
                                        this.movePrev();
                                        this.resetInterval();
                                        }
                                }.bind(this));
```

If anyone sees any potential issues with this method, feel free to chime in with a better answer (as like I said, it does seem rather basic)! Thanks.

edit:

Actually, for dynamic variables, this seems to be working within the js code:

```
    . . . . . 
     Plugin.prototype = {
                    init: function() {
                        var count = 1;
                        var listlength = $("li").length;
     . . . . . 
     . . . . . 
     . . . . . 
     . . . . . 
     if (this.options.nextButton && typeof(this.options.nextButton[0]) !== 'undefined')
    this.options.nextButton.click(function(e) {
        if (count == listlength) {
            return false;
        } else if (count < listlength) {
            count++;
            this.moveNext();
            this.resetInterval();
        }
    }.bind(this));
if (this.options.prevButton && typeof(this.options.prevButton[0]) !== 'undefined')
    this.options.prevButton.click(function(e) {
        if (count == 1) {
            return false;
        } else if (count > 0) {
            count--;
            this.movePrev();
            this.resetInterval();
        }
    }.bind(this));
```